# Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Contracts does not exist in Microsoft.ApplicationInsights

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I wanted to have a go at `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` telemetry. [Documentation claims that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationinsights.contracts.telemetrycontext.telemetrycontext.aspx) `TelemetryContext` is supposed to be in `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Contracts` namespace, however when I grab [Application Insights for Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web/) from nuget (it gets me `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` as dependency), it does not seem to have `Contracts` in it.

`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Contracts` [nuget search gives no results](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Contracts).

I must be missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on MSDN appears to be out of date.

In 1.1 of the Application Insights SDK (the latest, which I'm assuming you are using), has `TelemetryContext` in this namespace: `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts` (note DataContracts not just Contracts). I used Resharper to let it find the `TelemetryContext` class and it found it in this namespace in the core package (Microsoft.ApplicationInsights).

The SDK release notes do not mention anything specifically about this namespace moving however, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-release-notes-dotnet/.

Comment: i've forwarded this info to the people who own those docs, i'll see if this is just something that was overlooked and if they can update those.

Answer (score 1):

[API docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn817570.aspx) now updated. Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks for pointing this out.